Installing java server on cpanel
I want to run a java code for backend in cpanel domain service but my host only supports PHP. How can I install java on my cpanel domain?
I search about it on internet but I don't find anything about that.
Is there any way to do this with a WAR file and a tomcat server?

This seems more like a question for your hosting provider, but chances are the answer is "no".
